# Identity confusion Github Mac OS X

Tags: github

In spite of using `git config --global user.name` and `user.email` to my own credentials, the github installation on my Mac running Yosemite still tries to push as a previous user who worked with github on the same machine, so that my pushes fail as follows:

```
remote: Permission to MyRepository denied to OtherUser 
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MyUserName/MyRepository.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing git config user.name "myNameHere"? Maybe even try doing it manually. vi ~/.gitconfig

Comment: Thanks. However, the culprit simply turned out to be a password stored in OSX Keychain!

Answer (score 0):

you could have in your local project's .git folder's config some overrides to the global settings. For example, i use:

```
[core]
  ... core stuff ...
[remote "*someRepos*"]
  url = ssh://*someuser*@*somedomain.com*/*gitServerGitDirectory*/*someRepos*/*someProject*
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/*someRepos*/*
[branch "master"]
  remote = *someRepos*
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

where *someuser* overrides my local machine's global settings.